# Getting error while using virtualenv venv on fedora 26

Tags: python, virtualenv, fedora-26, pip

I installed virtualenv on fedora 26 using `pip3 install --user virtualenv`.
 System has both python 2.7 and python 3.6.
When I am creating a "virtualenv venv", I am getting this output and error.

> New python executable in /home/asraisingh/venv/bin/python2 
>   Also creating executable in /home/asraisingh/venv/bin/python
>   Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
>    Complete output from command /home/asraisingh/venv/bin/python2 - setuptools pip wheel:
>    Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 7, in 
>    File "/home/asraisingh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/**init**.py", line 7, in 
>    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/optparse.py", line 77, in 
>      import textwrap
>    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 10, in 
>      import string, re
>    
> File "string.py", line 1
>      KDE: 9
>         ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>   ----------------------------------------
>   ...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/home/asraisingh/.local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in 
>      sys.exit(main())
>    File "/home/asraisingh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
>      symlink=options.symlink)
>    File "/home/asraisingh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
>      download=download,
>    File "/home/asraisingh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
>      call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
>    File "/home/asraisingh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
>      % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
>   OSError: Command /home/asraisingh/venv/bin/python2 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1

Comment: Check if you have a file `string.py` in your current working directory.

Comment: Yes, I have string.py in my current working directory.

Comment: Thanks just renamed the string.py and it worked.

Comment: Great. Made my comment an answer. You can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have a file named `string.py` in your current working directory.
If so, rename, move, or delete it. This should solve your problem.